# SAML client as WSO2 ESB class mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using this [Access SAML Service](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/WSO2+Identity+Server+and+Claim+Aware+Proxy+Services+with+ESB) example as a class mediator to access a SAML secured endpoint web service. This example works fine when run as a standalone Java program with main method.

Here is how I use it from WSO2:

1) Create a HTTPS user name token Custom proxy on top of actual SAML secured web service
2) Create a class mediator of the above example.
3) Access the class mediator class to invoke the endpoint web service.

The class mediator seems to be working fine till it gets SAML token, however the remaining piece of logic of engaging Rampart for the endpoint and applying relevant security for the outgoing soap message doesn't seem to work.

Any pointers in this issue would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

i don't quite understand what the problem is, so what you got so far is something like this: [saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server)

And the problem is that you want to get the secure token from the SAMLResponse?.

Comment: Alejandro, the link I have given in my post points to a sample SAML client to hit the STS get the saml token and use the saml token to hit the actual web service. But that is from a standalone program. But when I do the same by packaging the client program and deploying it as a class mediator, it doesn't work. The program seems to be getting only the SAML assertion, but is not hitting the endpoint using that SAML assertion.

Comment: Abdul, can you upload your client on github or somethig like that to check it out?, it may be a dependency problem, or maybe your AS. At this time we are implementing WSO2 Prducts and i hope to help you.